# Citable Reference for Picard's Theorem in Banach Space

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if anyone knew of a legitimate citable reference where Picard's Theorem on the existence of solutions to ODEs in Banach space is proven? For some reason I can only find proofs for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in any of the books I have looked at. I realize that the proof is the same, but I would like to have a reference where I do not have to mention this fact.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Theorem 6, pp.117-118 of the survey paper

> Lobanov, S. G. & Smolyanov, O. G. "Ordinary differential equations in locally convex spaces". *Uspekhi Mat. Nauk*, 1994, **49**, 93-168

[(link to paper)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM1994v049n03ABEH002258). It being partially a survey paper, the theorem is stated without proof; if you want the proofs, you'd have to follow the references therein.